# How to handle message send from view class to dialog?

Tags: mfc, message, sdi, cview

I have SDI application that hand view, doc and mainframe. In view class, I have button to open another dialog, let say Chartering dialog. I would like to open that dialog and send initial value from view to assign some variable at dialog, but I can not catch message event at dialog class. Below as my code:

```
    // button onclick to show new dialog
    charteringDlg = new CharteringDlg();
// show chartering dialog
if(charteringDlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG_CHATTERING, GetDesktopWindow()))
{
    bChartering = true;
    charteringDlg->MoveWindow(900,300,450,300);
    charteringDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); 

    int temp = 12;

    GetMain()->SendMessage(UWM_MYMESSAGE_CHARTERING, 0,(LPARAM)&temp);
}
```

and in chartering dialog I handle message like below

```
ON_MESSAGE(UWM_MYMESSAGE_CHARTERING, &CharteringDlg::OnSetShowTemp)
```

chartering function

```
LRESULT CharteringDlg::OnSetShowTemp(WPARAM, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int * s = (int *)lParam;

    return 0;
}
```

I set break point at OnSetShowTemp() function but it cannot jump there.
Any idea would be great appreciated.

Comment: `GetMain()->SendMessage(UWM_MYMESSAGE_CHARTERING, 0,(LPARAM)&temp);` -> `charteringDlg->SendMessage(UWM_MYMESSAGE_CHARTERING, 0,(LPARAM)&temp);`. Or even simpler: `charteringDlg->thevalueorwhatever = 12`.

Comment: thank you very much, I don't think that is simple like that. if you post as answer, I will accept ^^

Comment: BTW, are you creating a modeless or a modal dialog? If it's a modeless one, googling _modeless dialog mfc_ might be helpful. You need to take care of the deletion of the modal dialog once it is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For assigning an initial value to one of your dialog's members you don't need to send it a message.

You can just assign the value directly:

So instead of

```
GetMain()->SendMessage(UWM_MYMESSAGE_CHARTERING, 0,(LPARAM)&temp);
```

you should have something like:

```
charteringDlg->thevalueorwhatever = 12;
```

---

And BTW:

```
GetMain()->SendMessage(UWM_MYMESSAGE_CHARTERING, 0,(LPARAM)&temp);
```

is wrong anyway, you should send the message to the dialog and not to the main window:

```
charteringDlg->SendMessage(UWM_MYMESSAGE_CHARTERING, 0,(LPARAM)&temp);
```

Comment: Or just expose public methods to get/set the value of a variable and keep the variable itself private.